# Chutzpah throws exception in TFS Build: 'executor://chutzpah-js/': Method not found: 'System.String .. get_SolutionDirectory()'

Tags: chutzpah

This is the exception:

`An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://chutzpah-js/': Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunContext.get_SolutionDirectory()'`

Everything else is fine and all unit tests are reported succeeded when the build is complete => the build should be ***succeeded***

But due to this exception, the build is considered ***partially succeeded*** which is very confusing.

I have been searching the internet, but still cannot find an answer. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: I have not seen this before. Could you give more information about the version of VS you, what OS and what other extensions you have installed?

Comment: @Matthew Manela: thanks very much for the response. I'm using VS 2012, TFS 2012, Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1. Installed extensions: TFS Build Extension. This problem occurs when I run unit tests against HTML files.

Comment: Could you file an issue on chutzpah.codeplex.com and attach a zip containing a repro of this issue?

Comment: @Matthew Manela: thank you very much for your time. I have just found out the answer to this question on the internet. It's claimed to be a bug of VS 2012, need to install VS 2012 Update 3 to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue when you deploy a VSIX package that depends on VS2013 version of IRunContext and try to run it in VS2012. This particular property is not available in the older version and you get an exception.